# Passing parameter to AJAX function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

This seems like the most stupid question, but I cannot get this to work. I want to pass a parameter into my AJAX function from my HTML button. Code looks like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="signupAjax(1)" value="Sign up>
```

My AJAX function:

```
function signupAjax(int select)
{
....
//for test purposes
alert(select);
}
```

For whatever reason, the parameter isn't getting passed into the AJAX function. Seems pretty basic, but can't seem to get it to work.

I know there's no actual AJAX code there, the actual code works perfectly well. It would just make life easier if I could pass this parameter.

Comment: remove the `int ` part and it should work

Comment: Yeah that's worked. Why don't I need to declare a type for that parameter?

Comment: because it is all var there isn't an int in JS just a var it is all object oriented.

Comment: cause its a scripting language with dynamic typing, search "dynamic typing" if you want more info about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/vnP4J/

**Description**: no need to say int select just select it is all objects in JS, next you missed a " in the input at the end.

**CODE:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function signupAjax(select)
    {
        //for test purposes
        alert(select);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="signupAjax(1)" value="Sign up" />
```

***Notes:*** One this isn't AJAX nor is it ASYNC it is just an onclick event.  It will be called synchronously.  Inside this function some AJAX/ASYNC call could happen and it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition should be

```
function signupAjax(select)
{
....
//for test purposes
alert(select);
}
```